# Second Integral of a function

Tags: calculus, integration

We have a function $f(x)$. We know that $f(0)=0$, that $f(x)=kf^{'}(x)$. How could we approach finding $f(x)$?

Comment: Ever solved something called a differential equation?

Comment: I am know studying integral calculus and I stumbled upon this.

Comment: I am curious to know, why'd you titled the post as "Second Integral of a function"?

Comment: I wanted to ask what is $f''(x)$ but edited it out to try and solve it on my own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what is called an 'ordinary differential equation', or ODE.

An algebraic equation consists of a variable which is a number $x$, and the equation gives you a relation the number satisfies, such as

$$ x^2 - 4x = 0$$
Meaning, "which number when you multiply it by itself and 4, and then subtract,  we'll get 0?"

The answer is $x=0 , x=4$ , there are 2 numbers which satisfy the equation above.

But in an ODE, the variable is a function and the equation gives us a relation between the function and its derivatives. For example, "Which function is equal to its derivative?", which can be written as
$$ f'(x) = f(x)$$
One can see that the solution is $f(x)=e^x$, which stays the same no matter how many times you derive it. More precisely, when you multiply $e^x$ by a constant number $A$ the equation still holds, so the solution is

$$ f(x) = A e^x $$

But how can you solve such equations when you don't 'just know' the answer?
Like regular equations, we know how to solve a very little amount of them, only specific types of ODE's are solvable in analytical methods.

Fortunately, your equation is one of them.

For any ODE of the following form:

$$ y' = g(x) \cdot y $$
you can solve like this:
$$ \frac{y'}{y} = g(x) $$
$$ (\ln y)' = g(x) $$
$$ \ln y = G(x) + c $$
$$ y = e^{G(x)+c} =e^c \cdot  e^{G(x)} $$
Where $c$ is a constant and $G(x)$ is the anti-derivative of $g(x)$. Because $c$ is an arbitrary number, so is $e^c$, and we can call it $A$, giving the result
$$ y= A \cdot e^{G(x)} $$
The world of ODE's is much wider than you think and is very useful in physics, where you see that the whole world is just a bunch of ODEs and PDEs (Partial Differnetial Equations, which I will not talk about).

I hope this helped!

Comment: For your case, $y = ky' \Rightarrow y' = \frac{1}{k} y$ , so $g(x)=\frac{1}{k}$ and $G(x) = \int \frac{1}{k}dx = \frac{x}{k} $.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Assume $k\ne 0$. One may consider
$$
g(x)=e^{-x/k}f(x)
$$ we have, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
g'(x)=-\frac1k[f(x)-k\cdot f'(x)]\cdot e^{-x/k}=0
$$What can be said about $g$?

Can you finish it?

Comment: The problem I see with this approach for someone *not*  studying differential equations is the almost "magic" way by which $\;g(x)\;$ is defined: how, why, from where...?

Comment: Why are you considering a different function $g(x)$, and are you assuming that $g'(x)=kg(x)$

Comment: @TheNotoriousSc I'm not assuming that $g'=kg$ I'm observing that $g'=0$ giving that $g=C$, $C$ necessarily a **constant**...

Comment: how do you know that $e^{-\frac{x}{k}}f(x)$ is constant?

Comment: @TheNotoriousSc Please see my previous comment.

Comment: Why is $g'=0$? Neither  necessarily  $f'=0$ nor $e^{\frac {-x}{k}}=0$. Excuse me if i am missing something as I mentioned above i am jusy now studying calculus.

Comment: @TheNotoriousSc We know that $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$, then with $g=e^{-x/k}f$, what is $g'$, what is $(e^{-x/k}f)'$? You have to do it to understand the above point of view.

Answer (score 1):

From $f(x)= kf'(x)= k\frac{df}{dx}$, we have, $\frac{df}{f}= \frac{1}{k}dx$.  Integrating both sides, $ln(f)= \frac{x}{k}+ C$, where C is the constant of integration.  Take the exponential of both sides to get $f(x)= e^{\frac{x}{k}+ C}= C'e^{\frac{x}{k}}$ where $C'= e^C$.  Since $f(0)= C'e^0= C'= 0$, The solution to this problem is f(x)= 0 for all x.

Answer (score 1):

An idea assuming $\;f(x)>0\;$ in some open interval (it is possible to fix this assumption and still work, yet I am trying a rather easy way and avoid absolute values and stuff):

$$f(x)=kf'(x)\implies\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac1k\stackrel{\text{integ. in both sides}}\implies\log f(x)=\frac xk+c\implies f(x)=Ce^{x/k} $$

with $\;C\;$ a constant. You can now input the condition $\;f(0)=0\;$ to find the constant...